# Kubernetes error while puling image from dockerhub

Tags: docker, minikube

Kuberenetes pull image from docker hub to run application on container getting error

> Failed to pull image "tutum/hello-world": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for GATEWAY.xxx.COM, not registry-1.docker.io

many suggest to look into link, however it is not available now

https://docs.docker.com/v1.13/engine/admin/systemd/#http-proxy

```
kind: service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name:helloworldservice
spec:
    selector:
        app: hello-world
    ports:
        protocol: "TCP"
        port: 8080
        targetport: 80
        nodeport: 3001
    type:LoadBalancer
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-world
        image: tutum/hello-world
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
```

> Failed to pull image "tutum/hello-world": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for GATEWAY.SPANSERVICES.COM, not registry-1.docker.io

Comment: fwiw, the link you posted is in the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20181113110715/https://docs.docker.com/v1.13/engine/admin/systemd/

Comment: Hi Dov, thanks for this, i have looked into this, however it did not help much.

Comment: This repo requires auth. If it needs x509 client certs, then you might just need to add those to k8s.

Comment: I am new to Kubernetes, I am trying to run container by pulling image from docker hub, I am using Hyperv for  VM. Could you please guide me how to resolve this issue

Comment: I'm sorry, but I probably can't. I was just pointing out that the link you posted requires auth. If you use an image from a public repo, it should work.

Comment: Yeah i am using image from public repo, but it is something internal security causing issue. Not able to identify the root cause.

Comment: You're probably being proxied and the mitm is trying to proxy ssl connections, too.

Comment: Yeah, that could be the reason, if you have idea on resolving that. Could you please guide me.

Comment: As you are using hyperv I assume you are using `Docker for Windows`. Please provide outuput of `nslookup docker.io`.
Have you tried to change DNS configuration to 3rd party (for example google 8.8.8.8) and restart docker `sudo systemctl restart docker` ?
Also, did you try https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy ?

Comment: @Pjoters thanks for your reply, you are correct i am using docker for windows, i have not tried to change the DNS configuration for 3rd party, also i am on corporate network.

I have tried to follow the steps from docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy, i was able to create directory /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d, however when i try to create http-proxy.conf i am getting error no permission .